# Adding Custom tab to product page dependant on category in Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have used the **following code**

> (https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/)

to create a module that adds a **custom tab** to our product pages. It works perfectly but I need to somehow change the module so that the custom tab only display on products in certain categories. Has anyone any suggestions on how to do this? Don't mind if the category numbers need to be hard coded as there won't be many! Please note we are using Magento 2.2.1

David

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing code after `<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>`, in `attribute.phtml` with following:

```
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<?php if ($_attributeType === 'your_type'):
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    if (strtolower($category->getName()) === 'category_to_display'): ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?> <!-- add your tab logic here -->
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != __('none')): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

change `your_type` to your declared attribute type, change `category_to_display` to your desired category name (chain || to add more categories to include tab). Add your code to `add your tab logic here`

Comment: Adrian,I believe attribute.phtml only exists in Magento 1 (?), we're using Magento 2.2.1 (question updated to reflect)

Comment: Hi David, I wrote answer on Magento 2.1. I'm pretty sure you should have this file on 2.2 too. Check ./vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml